# Equation and image aligned on beamer slide

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to make a beamer slide which has some matrix equations and an image lined up with each other.  Here is my attempt:

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{Transportation polytope constraints}
A $\nu$-index transportation polytope is a polytope with constraint equation $Ax = b$
with the entries of $b$ the $S^j_{m_j}$ sums along hyperplane slices, 
and each column of $A$ has $\nu$ ones and the remainder of the entries are zero.

{\small
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=.2\paperwidth{Presentation/BetterCubicPolytope.png} &
\[A = \left( \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}  \right)\qquad b = \left(\begin{array}{c}
14\\ 19\\ 20\\ 13\\26\\ 7 \end{array} \right) \]\end{tabular}}
\end{frame}
```

And what it ends up looking like is this:
[image: bad beamer slide]

Related is probably the fact that when I compile it complains about an end{frame} error (but still renders the slide).  When I replace the graphics with some sort of text it lines up the equation environment correctly, but I still get the error.

[image: good beamer slide]

Comment: one problem is a missing `]` at the end of the optional argument to `\includegraphics` -- add it after `.2\paperwidth`.  without a compilable example, i can't go further, but david is going in the right direction.

Comment: Ack, that seems to have been deleted when I was re-arranging my code into the format necessary for a code block (four spaces in for each line).  The process seemed unnecessarily cumbersome, is there some way beyond manually spacing each line?  Sorry about that.

Comment: above the block for entering answers, one of the icons is a pair of braces -- '{ }`.  run your cursor down the code block to highlight it, then click on that icon and it magically indents.  agreed -- having to type in the four leading spaces is at best a drag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference point of an image is on its bottom edge and the default reference point of a tabular or array is its vertical centre, which is why your image shows the bottom edge of the image in line with the array's centre.

Use `\begin{array}[b]` so the reference point for the array is on its bottom row, or use `\raisebox` to move the reference point of the image. In this case you probably want to use `\raisebox` so as not to change the alignment of the `=`.

```
 \raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics...
```

I can't comment in detail the errors you say your document generated as you have not provided a test document that generates them, fragments are not so useful as a complete document, but you seem to have the tabular specifications the wrong way round `\[` is a display environment so can be in a `p` column but not an `l` column, whereas the `\includegraphics` would be better in an `l`.

Comment: Swapping the p and l columns killed the weird error I was getting, thanks.  I didn't really understand what it was doing, I just got it off an example from google (for a different but similar type of problem with aligning things).  The raisebox command was able to fit everything perfectly as well!  I wasn't able to get adding a [b] in front of begin{array} though; it threw an error and from the documentation on arrays I don't see the optional command there.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to load `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` and use `valign=c` in

```
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=.2\paperwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Transportation polytope constraints}
A $\nu$-index transportation polytope is a polytope with constraint equation $Ax = b$
with the entries of $b$ the $S^j_{m_j}$ sums along hyperplane slices,
and each column of $A$ has $\nu$ ones and the remainder of the entries are zero.

{\small
\begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm} l}
\includegraphics[keepaspectratio=true,width=.2\paperwidth,valign=c]{example-image-a} &
\[A = \left( \begin{array}{c c c c c c c c}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}  \right)\qquad b = \left(\begin{array}{c}
14\\ 19\\ 20\\ 13\\26\\ 7 \end{array} \right) \]\end{tabular}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]